# histogram for known bin values

Tags: matlab

I have frequencies associated with known bins, example:

```
 bins = [0.542 0.583 0.626 0.673 0.723];
 freq = [888.558 1125.58 1434.21 1762.52 2058.5];
```

How do I draw a histogram of the values above (x =bins, y=freq)?

Comment: It's not giving me what I want. I have removed the semilog to eliminate any confusion. All I want to do is plot frequencies for known bins.

Comment: Opened and reclosed with a better duplicate.

Comment: Well I didn't see an answer that uses the hist function to do what I want, so I'm not sure why you think its duplicate!

Comment: Don't use the `hist` function.  Use the `stem` function.  You already have the bins and associated frequencies.